# How to send multiple parameters Ajax request with Jquery in Spring MVC Application.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

Here is my relevant codes.my out put is like this.
[image]

I need to send **region and tsrId as parameters** to query.
here is my code

**jsp**

Here is my ajax request with jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
            var region = document.getElementById('region').value;
            var tsrId = document.getElementById('tsrId').value;
            $('#tsrId').autocomplete({
                serviceUrl: 'getTsrId.html',
                data: ({queryData : {region:region,tsrId:tsrId}}),
                //delimiter: ",",
                transformResult: function(response) {
                return {suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {return { value: item.name, data: item.id };
                   })};}});});
</script>
```

here is the HTML form

```
  <td>Region</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="region" id="region"><div class="autocomplete-suggestions"></div></td>
  <td>TSR ID</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="tsrId" id="tsrId" maxlength="8"><div class="autocomplete-suggestions2"></div></td>
```

here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTsrId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<TSRMaster> getTsrId(@RequestParam String tagName,@RequestBody QueryData queryData) {
    List<TSRMaster> tsrMasterList=new ArrayList<TSRMaster>();
    tsrMasterList=gpsdao.getTsrIdList(queryData.getRegion(),queryData.getTsrId());
    return tsrMasterList;
}
```

here is my bean class for requestMapping

```
public class QueryData {

    private String region;
    private String  tsrId;

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }
    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }
    public String getTsrId() {
        return tsrId;
    }
    public void setTsrId(String tsrId) {
        this.tsrId = tsrId;
    }

}
```

Please help me to sort out this issue..is there any other alternative solution, please mention that path below
thanks.

Comment: I don't see this as spring / spring-mvc related. You seem to be having problem with JQuery autocomplete plugin

Comment: yes dear gerrytan.but its not get by mvc method.what is the error in my app.jackson mapper beans also added in servlet xml file

Comment: `data: ({queryData : {region:region,tsrId:tsrId}})` what is intent of using `()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I have been able to make this work so far is to call `JSON.stringify()` on the client, which turns a JavaScript Object into a JSON String. (To be cross browser compatible you would need [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js))

Then you send this as a String parameter to Spring and parse it there using the [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library.

**Sample Code:**

*Java Script*

```
data: ({queryData : JSON.stringify({region:region,tsrId:tsrId}})),
```

*Java*

```
RequestMapping(value = "/getTsrId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<TSRMaster> getTsrId(@RequestParam String tagName,@RequestParam String queryData) {

    ObjectMapper myMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    QueryData myQueryData = myMapper.readValue(queryData, QueryData.class);

    List<TSRMaster> tsrMasterList=new ArrayList<TSRMaster>();
    tsrMasterList=gpsdao.getTsrIdList(myQueryData.getRegion(),queryData.getTsrId());
    return tsrMasterList;
}
```

Comment: please can u show its with code.i added it but its not worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson framework for JSON java transformation. Then you can use following method to send data to the controller from the view.

Add jackson jars to the project.

jackson-core-2.0.5
jackson-databind-2.0.5
jackson-annotation-2.0.5

Add following code to WebApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
        url: getTsrId.html,
        type: 'GET',
        data: "region=" + region + "&tsrId=" + tsrId,           
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(response){

//response here
}
});
```

Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getTsrId", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<TSRMaster> getTsrId(
                @ModelAttribute(value = "queryData") QueryData queryData) {
        List<TSRMaster> tsrMasterList = new ArrayList<TSRMaster>();
        tsrMasterList = gpsdao.getTsrIdList(queryData.getRegion(),queryData.getTsrId());
        return tsrMasterList;
    }
```